# The imported project "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" was not found

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, import

I am getting this error when i load up one of the projects in VB.net 2010. I open up where it has the line its referring too and it says:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
```

Where (and what) is it looking for? I open that directory and see all kinds of files but i am unsure of what file it can not load or find?

The complete error is:

> G:\i7 laptop code\BarcodeGenerator\BarcodeGenerator\BarcodeGenerator.vbproj(108,3):
>   The imported project
>   "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets"
>   was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is
>   correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Any help would be great!

David

Comment: It seems like your .NET Framework installation is corrupted. Try reinstalling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected by repairing .NET framework 4.0 again thanks to @James Didzun